# How can I reduce the space between two discrete values in the x-axis?

Tags: r

First of all, I would like to do this without ggplot.

I have this script for a boxplot:

```
data <- data.frame(
  u    = c(0.522, 0.488, 0.474, 0.443, 0.510, 0.443, 0.420, 0.554, 0.333, 0.414,
           0.467, 0.606, 0.588),
  ub   = c(0.594, 0.568, 0.578, 0.523, 0.577, 0.501, 0.522, 0.623, 0.498, 0.511,
           0.544, 0.654, 0.639),
  nu   = c(0.646, 0.620, 0.644, 0.607, 0.667, 0.614, 0.631, 0.701, 0.586, 0.589,
           0.664, 0.739, 0.744),
  nub  = c(0.733, 0.701, 0.700, 0.698, 0.724, 0.701, 0.722, 0.777, 0.630, 0.663,
           0.703, 0.78, 0.787),
  wnub = c(0.815, 0.782, 0.757, 0.764, 0.792, 0.771, 0.838, 0.860, 0.700, 0.703,
           0.774, 0.837, 0.863))
boxplot(data, las=1, par(mar=c(7.5, 4.2, 0.25, 0.15)), axes=FALSE, xlab=NA,
        ylab=NA, boxwex=.4, outline=FALSE, ylim=c(0:1))
box()
labnames = c("Unigrams",
             "Unigrams\n& Bigrams",
             "Noun Unigrams",
             "Noun Unigrams\n& Noun Bigrams",
             "Noun Unigrams\n& Noun Bigrams\n(positional weights)")
axis(side=1, tck=-0.025, labels=FALSE)
axis(side=1, lwd=0, labels=FALSE, at=c(1:5), cex.axis=1)
text(seq(1, 5, by=1), par("usr")[3]-.2, labels=labnames, srt=-90,
     xpd=TRUE, adj=.25)
axis(side=2, tck=-0.02, labels=NA)
axis(side=2, lwd=0, cex.axis=1, las=1)
mtext(side=1, "Feature Sets", line=6.5, cex=1.5)
mtext(side=2, "F-Score", line=3, cex=1.5)
```

which produces the following figure:

[image: boxplot]

I am annoyed by the amount of whitespace this is wasting. One way I've been trying to reduce the space is by bringing the discrete x-axis values closer together by using "asp", but it doesn't change anything. How can I do this so that the huge gap between the boxes are reduced?

Also, if there any other ways to reduce the whitespace in this picture, please share your thoughts.

Comment: That is an interesting approach ... hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately, I can't go down that path because I have to include the R plot in a latex document, and compiling (I use `pdflatex`) always leads to quality loss with jpg and png images. I have to stick to a pdf output, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1:** If you're saving images as PDF for Latex, you can set the width and height with `pdf(file=file, width=width, height=height)`. Then you can ignore the `boxwex` parameter altogether.

**Option 2:** Alternatively, you can use the `at` parameter to tell `boxplot` where in the X axis it should place the boxes:

```
at.x <- seq(1,by=.5,length.out=5) # set here the X-axis positions
boxplot(data, par(mar=c(8.5, 4.2, 0.25, 0.15)), outline=FALSE,
        cex.lab=1.5, ylab="F-score", xlab=NA, las=3, names=labnames,
        boxwex=.4, ylim=c(0:1),
        at=at.x)
# display the X-axis name
mtext(side=1, "Feature Sets", line=7.2, cex=1.5)
```

See that the code is also heavily simplified. You can further play with the `xlim` parameter to `boxplot` to reduce the inner margins of the plot. Try for instance `xlim=c(0.8,3.2)`. Result:

[image]

**Option 3:** If you *really* are in a quest to save space, you can use colors and a legend:

```
cols <- c("white","red","yellow","green","blue")
boxplot(data, par(mar=c(0.2, 3.2, 0.25, 0.15)), outline=FALSE,
        axes=F, ylab=NA, xlab=NA, names=NA, col=cols)
box()
axis(2)
mtext(side=2,"F-score",line=2.2)
legend("bottomright", cex=.8, fill=cols,
       c("Unigrams", "Unigrams & Bigrams", "Noun Unigrams",
         "Noun Unigrams & Noun Bigrams",
         "Noun Unigrams & Noun Bigrams (positional weights)"))
```

[image]

Finally, why set the limits of the Y-axis to 0 and 1? That is wasting a lot of space there. Also, why remove outliers? Just asking as an IR researcher myself :-)

Comment: Is there something similar to option 2 for ggplot2?

Answer (score 2):

Two things up front:

- `boxwex=0.4` is narrowing the boxes horizontally.
- `ylim=c(0,1)` is opening up space vertically (I don't think vertical
  whitespace is a problem, per se).

The amount of horizontal whitespace with `boxwex` is proportional, so
if you create an image 640 pixels or 6400 pixels wide, `boxwex` is
still giving you 40% horizontal coverage (80% is the default).
Regardless, `boxplot` is going to spread across the entire width of
the figure.

@AndreSilva started on one technique.With `jpeg()` (and `png()`,
`pdf()`, and `svg()`), you can specify the dimensions of the captured
image. For `jpeg` and `png`, the units for `width` and `height` are in
pixels; I find the default resolution of 72 dpi to be a bit ratchety,
so know that you can change the `res`. Note that this will affect how
the fonts fit as well, not just making the lines appear less ratchety.
(BTW: I typically recommend against `jpeg()` unless you are including
high numbers of colors and/or overlaying actual images, but YMMV.)

Unless you truly need to set a specific aspect ratio, using `asp`
really only gives you an idea of the ratio to use between the width
and height, in my experience. However, even in R-studio, you can
change the apparent dimensions of the graph to get a better idea of
what a rendered/captured image will look like.

If you are really trying to be more efficient with space, you can
bring the x-axis labels up closer to the boxes. You can either place
them (as shown here) all lined up (my preferred), or optionally (with
my commented-out line below) place each one text below its respective
box.

```
par(mar=c(3,4.5,0,0)+0.1)
bp <- boxplot(data, names=NA, ylim=c(0,1), axes=FALSE,
              outline=FALSE, cex.lab=1.5, col='#55ff55')
axis(2, las=1)
#text(1:5, bp$stats[1,] - 0.05, labnames, srt=-90, xpd=TRUE, adj=c(0,0.5))
text(1:5, rep(0.3,5), labnames, srt=-90, xpd=TRUE, adj=c(0,0.5))
mtext('Feature Sets', side=1, line=2, at=0.5, adj=0, cex=1.5)
mtext('F-Score', side=2, line=2.5, at=0, adj=0, cex=1.5)
savePlot(file='Rplot.png', type='png', res=150)
```

At this point, many of the tweaking points are as much personal
preference as they are Tufte-ian. (Something else I'd consider doing
is adding color to the boxes with `col` in the `boxplot` call, to make
them stand out a bit from the white background.)

[image: Rplot, 625x357]

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are increasing the space between boxes by setting the boxwex=.4 parameter. Setting that to boxwex=.8 will make the boxplots wider and reduce the whitespace.

Alternatively, if you are interested in "moving" the white space to the edges of the plot rather than between the boxes, you can explicitly set an xlim= parameter. By default, since you have 5 groups they are plotted at 1,2,3,4,5 and the default is xlim=c(.5,5.5). You can set the xlim=c(0,6) or xlim=c(-1,7) which will draw a wider data range, btu your data will be moved closer to the center. If you do that, you will also want to comment out the `axis(side=1, lwd=0, labels=FALSE, at=c(1:5), cex.axis=1)` as that may draw extra tick marks (and I'm not sure why it's there in the first place).