# Change width of individual boxes in boxplot in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

**How can I reduce the width of each individual boxplot in Base R?**

I do not want to change the *relative* sizes of the boxplots, which I understand can be done with the `width` argument

(this is not the same question as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418811/how-can-i-reduce-the-space-between-two-discrete-values-in-the-x-axis), which asks about removing whitespace)

```
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl,
        data=mtcars)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the default width using the `boxwex=` parameter. More information on these parameters are actually found in the `?bxp` help page which does the boxplot drawing. There's a mention of this when describing the `...` parameter in the `?boxplot` help page.

```
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, boxwex=.2)
```

[image: narrow box plots]

Answer (score 1):

The graphic parameter you want is `boxwex`, see `help("bxp")`, the function that does the plotting part of the box-and-whiskers plot.

```
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, boxwex = 0.1)
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, boxwex = 0.4)
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, boxwex = 0.8)
par(old_par)
```

[image]